# Count length of black pixels on image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am using OpenCV to manipulate some images.

Suppose that `image.png` is black/white image (only `B` or `W` for pixel colors).

For example, if we print the colors for 3rd line, it could be:

```
WWWWWBBBWWWWWWBBBBBBWWWWWBBWWWW
```

I'd like to save info on each sequence of black pixels, I mean, I'd like to be able to compute, for each row, the values:

`number of black sequences in row i:` (`3` on example above)

`x-coordinate of end pixels for each black sequence in row i:` (`6,8` and `15,20` and `26,27` on example above)

`length of each black sequence on row i:` (`l1=3,l2=6,l3=2` on example above) (this is easy assuming item above is done)

I'm using some `for` loop and testing if color is black. When it is black, I save the `x` coordinate and start other loop inside to run from this coordinate to the end of line, testing if the color is white. When it finds white color, it stops and save the previous coordinate.

This works to compute only the length of first sequence of black pixels. I don't know how to go to next (I even don't know how many there are).

Here is the main part of code (with some trash code):

```
for(int y=0;y<img.rows;y++) //img.rows
    {
        for(int x=0;x<img.cols;x++)
        {
            Vec3b color = image.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y));
            printf("(%d,%d,%d)\n",color[1],color[2],color[3]);
            if(color[0] == 0 && color[1] == 0 && color[2] == 0)
            {
                cor[0]='B';
                ymax = y;
                if (ymin == -1) { ymin = y; }
                int xmin = x;
                int diam_esq = img.cols/2-xmin;
                double dist_esq = sqrt( (x-img.cols/2)*(x-img.cols/2) + (y-img.rows/2)*(y-img.rows/2) );
                for(int z=x;z<img.cols;z++)
                {
                    Vec3b colorz = image.at<Vec3b>(Point(z,y));
                    if(colorz[0] == 255 && colorz[1] == 255 && colorz[2] == 255)
                    {
                        int xmax = z-1;
                        int diam_dir = xmax-img.cols/2;
                        double dist_dir = sqrt( (z-1-img.cols/2)*(z-1-img.cols/2) + (y-img.rows/2)*(y-img.rows/2) );
                        int diam = xmax - xmin;
                        //printf("y=%*d, xmin=%*d, xmax=%*d, esq=%*d, dir=%*d, diam=%*d\n",5,y,5,xmin,5,xmax,5,diam_esq,5,diam_dir,5,diam);
                        printf("%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*d%*f%*f\n",5,y,5,xmin,5,xmax,5,diam_esq,5,diam_dir,5,diam,13,dist_esq,13,dist_dir);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        //break; // only y=0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that does what you want. It only prints out results. It doesn't save them anywhere but I assume you'll know how to do this.

To find black sequences in each row, there is no need to do nested for loops for each sequence, just keep track of whether or not you're inside a black sequence and if yes, of where it began. Also, I use `Mat::ptr` to allow for a more efficient traversal of your image, row by row.

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++) {
    Vec3b* ptr = image.ptr<Vec3b>(i);
    bool blackSequence = false;
    int blackSequenceStart = -1;
    int numberOfBlackSequences = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++) {
        Vec3b color = ptr[j];
        if(color[0] == 0 && !blackSequence) { // this is assuming that all pixels are either white or black
            blackSequence = true;
            blackSequenceStart = j;
            numberOfBlackSequences++;
        }
        if(color[0] == 255 && blackSequence) {
            blackSequence = false;
            cout << "Row " << i << ": Sequence " << numberOfBlackSequences << " starts at " << blackSequenceStart 
                   << " and finishes at " << j - 1 << ". Total length: " << j - blackSequenceStart << endl;
        }
        if(j == image.cols - 1 && blackSequence) {
            blackSequence = false;
            cout << "Row " << i << ": Sequence " << numberOfBlackSequences << " starts at " << blackSequenceStart 
                   << " and finishes at " << j << ". Total length: " << j - blackSequenceStart + 1 << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understood your code. It looks to work. So it helps to confirm some problem I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43020806/1778537 I run your code on this https://i.imgur.com/UjToips.png and the result is not constant. Almost sure that the problem is how OpenCV reads the pixel color. If you have time, please, read the cited post.

Comment: The length should be `61` if we test on https://i.imgur.com/UjToips.png since the black region is a rectangle from `(20,10)` to `(80,50)` (`width=60`, `height=40`). Do you agree?

Comment: @Sigur Yes, it should be 61. If you take a smaller example with a rectangle from (0,0) to (1,1), then the width is two pixels => 2

Comment: Strange. It is printing a lot of lengths: some times it is  `20,21,20` (sum to 61). But for some rows it is `66`. I have to study.

Comment: What should be `color = ptr[j]`? A row or a column? In any case, what should be its 0 coordinate `color[0]`?

Comment: Color is a Vec3b object (the color of a pixel). I'm assuming here that all your pixels are either (0,0,0) or (255,255,255) which means that we only care about the first coordinate of color (the blue channel). If you have grey pixels (not perfectly black or white) then the code above won't work.

Comment: As far as I know I was using a real BW image (https://i.imgur.com/UjToips.png). Let me check again.

Comment: There are gray pixels on the sides of the rectangle in this image.

Comment: Did you check only looking to image or did you print all pixel colors? If you have ImageMagick you can check `convert rect.png -format %c histogram:info:-`